# 500 Internal Server Error using apache 2.4 and silverstripe 3.1.12

Tags: apache, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04, lamp, silverstripe

I have installed silverstripe using composer

```
composer create-project silverstripe/installer /var/www/
```

When I go to local host I get "Internal Server Error".
The apache2 error.log file gives me:

```
[Sat Apr 11 19:12:21.824829 2015] [core:error] [pid 3250] [client 127.0.0.1:58951] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

A friend suggested it might be a permissions issue, we tried

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Which didn't work.

Any ideas?
p.s. I'm new to web dev and have tried a few IRC channels for help.

Comment: have there been any other files in /var/www/ and what does your .htaccess look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be one of these

1. a misconfigured `.htaccess` file (or `VirtualHosts`) that causes recursive requests being made. Try this snippet for the respective file of yours.

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. wrong permissions. Try to set the permission set of `*.php` files to `0644` or `0755`

Comment: Is the problem solved? Any new entries in error.log ?

Comment: Sorry, it was very simple, I had silver stripe install in www/silver stripe instead of being directly in www